# Limit in results(docs) by facet

Tags: solr, solr4, faceted-search, solr4j

I want to show max 5 results(docs) from each facets on first page. How can I achieve it in Solr 4.x

for e.g I have thousands of matching products(docs) in TV, Music System, Books etc categories. If I search "Music" keyword, I should get max 5 matching results(docs) from all categories.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I want to set limit on results(docs) not on facet list. And this limit is on each facet not on all result. If there are 3 categories, 15 results(docs) can be display on page, if 4, max 20 results(docs) can be display.

Comment: so please update your question, right now it's controversial

Answer (score 0):

To limit search results you need to use param `rows=5`
For more info - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#rows